# Disable scrolling in core-plot graph iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, graph, core-plot

I would like to disable scrolling in core-plot graph. I have an idea about constricting the CPXYPlotSpace range by setting the properties globalXrange and globalYRange, but this doesn't solve my purpose as I need to make the axis fix and do not want to have scrolling effect on my graph. Earlier version of core-plot used to have this functionality but it seems that with latest version scrolling has been enabled in CPGraphHostingView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be disabled by default. Make sure the `allowsUserInteraction` property of your plot space is set to `NO`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eric but if I set plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=FALSE then in that case graph axis will not be visible any workaround for it?

Comment: allowsUserInteraction shouldn't affect the display of the axes at all.